# Laravel scheduler says "No scheduled commands are ready to run."

Tags: cron, laravel-5

I've setup a command like this:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('feeds:fetch')->everyFiveMinutes();
}
```

I've setup a cron job to run `php artisan schedule:run`

When I run that line on dev's terminal it runs the task OK. On Prod it returns "No scheduled commands are ready to run."

Any way to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fine folks at Larachat (https://larachat.slack.com/) helped me out debug this issue.

The problem was with my crontab. I was setting the crontab to execute the artisan scheduler as follows:

```
*/1 * * * * php /path/to/artisan schedule:run
```

(meaning execute *every 1st minute* of every hour every day.)

When it should be:

```
* * * * * php /path/to/artisan schedule:run
```

(meaning execute *every minute* of every hour every day.)

So, when I manually ran cron on a non-1st minute of every hour, it didn't run at all.

Comment: “No scheduled commands are ready to run.” How is it connected to cron? You can run the artisan command on command line without cron. The description of the problem is incorrect I suppose.

Comment: To be fair, it wasn't cron's fault, but it was connected in that the failure was that I had an error in my crontab, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution for this problem. Just add the timestamp in the $schedule.

You can change the command name, time and timezone according to your requirements.

```
$schedule->command('tenam:before')
        ->dailyAt('22:28')->timezone('Asia/Kolkata');
```